# Laravel alguna forma de auto importar todo un directorio

Tags: php, laravel

tengo el siguiente directorio:

```
numeros/
         ./uno
         ./dos
         ./tres
         ./cuatro
```

¿Puedo hacer de alguna manera un  **use** del directorio  numeros e importar sus directorios?
Cada  numero es una clase

Comment: Puedes usar [`glob()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.glob.php)

Comment: Voy a editar la pregunta, para aclar mi caso

Answer (score 0):

Hasta PHP 8.0, no.

Ten en cuenta que la instrucción `use` no importa nada, es solo una forma de crear un alias para una clase, interfaz o espacio de nombres. Por lo tanto, no tiene sentido crear un solo alias para varias cosas a la vez.

La inclusión del archivo que contiene una clase no se hará hasta la primera vez que utilices dicha clase.

Comment: Voy a editar la pregunta, para aclar mi caso